# How to get more info from client on problems when developing an X Server

Tags: x11

I trying to develop an X11 Server and whilst testing an XClient the Client is closing the session

```
  XIO:  fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server "family-desktop:3.0"
  after 35 requests (28 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I cannot spot the error in my code with either request 28 or request 35. Is there a way to get more information about what the client is unhappy about.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use X protocol tracing proxy like [xtruss](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/xtruss/) or wireshark with X11 dissector.